# What is FeatureFlags, and how to change it?

Tags: android, bluetooth

`packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/core/FeatureFlags.java`

Does anyone know what this class does and how to modify these settings?

I want to know how to make android auto reconnect classic bluetooth device, and see this class in android source code:

```java
void autoConnect() {
    if (mAdapterService.getState() != BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
        Log.e(TAG, "autoConnect: BT is not ON. Exiting autoConnect");
        return;
    }
    
    if (mAdapterService.isQuietModeEnabled()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "autoConnect() - BT is in quiet mode. Not initiating autoConnect");
        return;
    }

    final BluetoothDevice mostRecentlyActiveA2dpDevice =
        mDatabaseManager.getMostRecentlyConnectedA2dpDevice();
        
    if (mostRecentlyActiveA2dpDevice != null) {
        debugLog("autoConnect: Device "
                + mostRecentlyActiveA2dpDevice
                + " attempting auto connection");
        autoConnectHeadset(mostRecentlyActiveA2dpDevice);
        autoConnectA2dp(mostRecentlyActiveA2dpDevice);
        autoConnectHidHost(mostRecentlyActiveA2dpDevice);
        return;
    }
    
    // What is FeatureFlags? and how it works? can I change it?
    if (!mFeatureFlags.autoConnectOnHfpWhenNoA2dpDevice()) {
        debugLog("HFP auto connect is not enabled");
        return;
    }
}
```

I don't know how `FeatureFlag` works, if anyone know, please tell me, thanks!